# AGM "expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenChecked" Error when trying to display map

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular5

I'm trying to integrate AGM in my Bootstrap 5 application, but the map doesn't appear, and I see errors in my browser.
I think this have something to do with the fact I am manipulating url, and specifically the `deviceId`.

**Angular & AGM versions**
Angular version v5.2.9 & agm/core v1.0.0-beta.2

Do you have any idea on how to fix this ?

`deviceLocation.component.ts`

```
@Component({
selector: 'deviceLocation',
templateUrl: 'deviceLocation.template.html'
})
export class DeviceLocationComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit  {
 title = 'My first AGM project';
 lat = 51.678418;
 lng = 7.809007;

public constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router,  private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.nav = document.querySelector('nav.navbar');
    this.token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    localStorage.setItem('currentRoute', 'deviceLocation');
}

public ngOnInit(): any {
    this.nav.className += ' white-bg';

    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.deviceId = params['id']; // Parameter Name
    });

    const myHeader = new Headers();
    myHeader.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    myHeader.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token);

    this.http.get(GlobalsSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'devices/' + this.deviceId + '/locations', { headers: myHeader })
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log(response.json());
          this.data = response.json();
        },
        error => {
          // alert(error.text());
          this.device_locations_error_pres = true;
          this.device_locations_err = error.json();
        }
      );
   }
}
```

Error:

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined: /device//deviceInformation'. Current value: 'undefined: /device/5aba4ffa8500f4000515ee07/deviceInformation'.
Stack trace:
viewDebugError@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:9991:32
expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:9969:12
checkBindingNoChanges@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:10136:15
checkNoChangesNodeInline@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14184:9
checkNoChangesNode@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14158:9
debugCheckNoChangesNode@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14987:24
debugCheckDirectivesFn@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14889:13
View_NavigationComponent_3/<@ng:///LayoutsModule/NavigationComponent.ngfactory.js:209:21
debugUpdateDirectives@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14871:12
checkNoChangesView@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13996:5
callViewAction@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14349:21
execEmbeddedViewsAction@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14327:17
checkNoChangesView@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13997:5
callViewAction@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14349:21
execComponentViewsAction@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14301:13
checkNoChangesView@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13999:5
callViewAction@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14349:21
execComponentViewsAction@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14301:13
checkNoChangesView@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13999:5
callViewAction@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14349:21
execEmbeddedViewsAction@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14327:17
checkNoChangesView@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13997:5
callViewAction@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14349:21
execComponentViewsAction@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14301:13
checkNoChangesView@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13999:5
callWithDebugContext@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:15272:39
debugCheckNoChangesView@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14816:12
ViewRef_.prototype.checkNoChanges@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:11807:19
ApplicationRef.prototype.tick/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:6125:62
ApplicationRef.prototype.tick@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:6125:17
next/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:5956:99
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:17
onInvoke@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:4965:24
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:17
Zone.prototype.run@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:138:24
NgZone.prototype.run@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:4782:54
next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:5956:69
EventEmitter.prototype.subscribe/schedulerFn<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:4547:36
SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:245:13
SafeSubscriber.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:192:17
Subscriber.prototype._next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:133:9
Subscriber.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:97:13
Subject.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subject.js:65:17
EventEmitter.prototype.emit@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:4527:24
checkStable@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:4930:13
onHasTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:4978:21
ZoneDelegate.prototype.hasTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:441:21
ZoneDelegate.prototype._updateTaskCount@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:461:17
Zone.prototype._updateTaskCount@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:285:17
Zone.prototype.runTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:205:25
drainMicroTaskQueue@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:595:25
NavigationComponent.html:34:71
```

and

```
ERROR CONTEXT {…}
elDef: Object { nodeIndex: 21, bindingIndex: 9, outputIndex: 1, … }​
elView: Object { def: {…}, parent: {…}, state: 1052, … }
nodeDef: Object { nodeIndex: 23, bindingIndex: 12, outputIndex: 2, … }​
nodeIndex: 23​view: Object { def: {…}, parent: {…}, state: 1052, … }​__proto__: {…}​​component:
Getter​​componentRenderElement: 
Getter​​constructor: function DebugContext_()​​context: Getter​​elOrCompView: 
Getter​​injector: Getter​​logError: function logError()​​providerTokens: 
Getter​​references: Getter​​renderNode: 
Getter​​__proto__: Object { … } NavigationComponent.html:34:71
```

Comment: try to move your code on life cycle hook : ngAfterViewInit. This issue is come when you change date on the middle of dirty checking (process who update your DOM according to your current application state).

Comment: see this https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Comment: you mean replacing `ngOnInit` with `ngAfterViewInit` ?

Comment: yes, and thanks @Vikas for your link